# Mindbender: Is trigger with spatial intersect AND nearest neighbor possible?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, spatial

The following trigger works great. Upon inert or update, a geography point gets tagged with spatial coordinates and some attributes from intersection polygons.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[BACTERIOLOGICAL_GEOMETRY]
ON [dbo].[BACTERIOLOGICAL]
after INSERT,UPDATE NOT FOR REPLICATION
AS   
BEGIN    
  SET NOCOUNT ON;  

  UPDATE p SET  
         SHAPE = CASE WHEN i.SHAPE IS NOT NULL   
        THEN p.SHAPE ELSE Geography::STPointFromText('POINT('  
          + CAST(p.LON AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' '   
          + CAST(p.LAT AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 4269) END,  
      LON = CASE WHEN p.SHAPE IS NULL THEN p.LON ELSE p.SHAPE.Long END,  
      LAT = CASE WHEN p.SHAPE IS NULL THEN p.LAT ELSE p.SHAPE.Lat END,
    QuadName = COALESCE(b.name, p.QuadName),
    Watershed = COALESCE(c.HUC_12_Name, p.Watershed),
    County = COALESCE(d.Name, p.County), 
    State= COALESCE(e.Name, p.State),
    PARKDISTRICT = COALESCE(f.District, p.PARKDISTRICT)

  FROM  BACTERIOLOGICAL
     AS p 
  INNER JOIN  
    inserted AS i 
    ON i.globalid = p.globalid 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN USGS_24K_TOPOMAP_BOUNDARIES AS b 
    ON b.Shape.STIntersects(i.Shape) = 1 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN WATERSHEDS AS c
    ON c.Shape.STIntersects(i.Shape) = 1 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN GRSM_COUNTIES AS d
    ON d.Shape.STIntersects(i.Shape) = 1 
              LEFT OUTER JOIN GRSM_States AS e
    ON e.Shape.STIntersects(i.Shape) = 1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN GRSM_SUB_RANGER_DISTRICTS AS f 
ON f.Shape.STIntersects(i.Shape) = 1 
  ; 
END
GO
```

I'd like to add the following to the trigger, to also include a nearest neighbor determination on update or insert:

```
update  [dbo].[BACTERIOLOGICAL]
set StreamName = sname
from(
Select
dbo.BACTERIOLOGICAL.StreamName,
fnc.GNIS_Name as sname
from
dbo.BACTERIOLOGICAL
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 GNIS_Name, shape                   
FROM dbo.NHDFLOWLINE WITH(index ([S208_idx]))                  
WHERE NHDFLOWLINE.Shape.STDistance(dbo.BACTERIOLOGICAL.Shape) IS NOT NULL
                  ORDER BY NHDFLOWLINE.Shape.STDistance(dbo.BACTERIOLOGICAL.Shape) ASC) fnc)d
```

But I just can't seem to make it work. I've tried lots of permutations of adding code block #2 to code block # 1, and get nothing but errors. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most elegant solution, but it works!

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[BACTERIOLOGICAL_GEOMETRY]
    ON [dbo].[BACTERIOLOGICAL]
    after INSERT,UPDATE NOT FOR REPLICATION
    AS   
    BEGIN    
      SET NOCOUNT ON;  

      UPDATE p SET  
             SHAPE = CASE WHEN i.SHAPE IS NOT NULL   
            THEN p.SHAPE ELSE Geography::STPointFromText('POINT('  
              + CAST(p.LON AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' '   
              + CAST(p.LAT AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 4269) END,  
          LON = CASE WHEN p.SHAPE IS NULL THEN p.LON ELSE p.SHAPE.Long END,  
          LAT = CASE WHEN p.SHAPE IS NULL THEN p.LAT ELSE p.SHAPE.Lat END,
        QuadName = COALESCE(b.name, p.QuadName),
        Watershed = COALESCE(c.HUC_12_Name, p.Watershed),
        County = COALESCE(d.Name, p.County), 
        State= COALESCE(e.Name, p.State),
        PARKDISTRICT = COALESCE(f.District, p.PARKDISTRICT),
        UNITCODE = 'GRSM',
        RESTRICTION = 'UNR',
        UNITNAME = 'GRSM',
        DATUM = 'NAD83',
        COORD_SYSTEM = 'GCS',
        COORD_UNITS = 'dd',
        UTM_ZONE = '17',
        StreamName = COALESCE(g.GNIS_Name, p.StreamName)

      FROM  BACTERIOLOGICAL
         AS p 

      INNER JOIN  
        inserted AS i 
        ON i.globalid = p.globalid 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN USGS_24K_TOPOMAP_BOUNDARIES AS b 
        ON b.Shape.STIntersects(i.Shape) = 1 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN WATERSHEDS AS c
        ON c.Shape.STIntersects(i.Shape) = 1 
              LEFT OUTER JOIN GRSM_COUNTIES AS d
        ON d.Shape.STIntersects(i.Shape) = 1 
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN GRSM_States AS e
        ON e.Shape.STIntersects(i.Shape) = 1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN GRSM_SUB_RANGER_DISTRICTS AS f 
    ON f.Shape.STIntersects(i.Shape) = 1 
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 GNIS_Name, shape                   
    FROM dbo.NHDFLOWLINE WITH(index ([S208_idx]))                  
    WHERE NHDFLOWLINE.Shape.STDistance(i.Shape) IS NOT NULL
                      ORDER BY NHDFLOWLINE.Shape.STDistance(i.Shape) ASC) as g
      ; 
    END
    GO
```